# Jira integration in Leverice

Tags: jira, integration, message

I'm setting up a new Jira integration in Leverice and had a question about the channel creation dialogue window. When it pops up, there are a handful of fields in the window. In the project key field, I came up with a new project key ABCD, but the events stream doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering if it's because of that field. Can I choose anything I want to enter, for example, as the project key, or do I need it to match what I have in Jira exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one field in that dialogue window is permissive, the rest are mandatory as follows --

Display Name: this can be anything you choose, for example you can call it Acme Dev

Project key: this must be the root acronym of all your existing Jira items. For example if your Jira items are ACME-1454, ACME-2595, etc. then your project key should be entered as ACME

Site name: this must be the root url of your Jira space, for example https://acmecompany.atlassian.net

Atlassian id (email): this must be the email address you use to login to Jira with admin rights

Jira api token: to obtain this token go to your Jira website, click on your Profile avatar in the bottom left corner, click on “Profile”, then click “Manage your account”. Next, select “Security” and scroll down to “Create and manage API tokens”. Click on it, create a token, and copy and paste it back into the Leverice pop-up box.